# Magento 2.1.1 Missing tables in Database

Tags: magento2

I am working on a fresh install of Magento 2.1 and lately updated to 2.1.1 and I am having problems getting Magento to send emails. Order confirmations emails... Searching online I found that I should look into my cron jobs and everything seems to work as supposed. Then I went to look into the database for the related tables and all "core_email_queue" tables are missing.

What should I do? The Magento installation was done by Nexcess (turnkey hosting). I have heard of Magento database repair tool but found nothing for Magento 2.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Download that version locally & upload that table on server or take support for Nexcess via Submitting Ticket

Comment: This issue occurs when asynchronous email sending is set to enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento 2.1.1 does not have "core_email_queue" table. So you don't need to worry about 'missing table'. You need to check log file for real error for why emails are not sent.

Comment: I want to know how asynchronous email sending works in Magento 2